# How to calculate Reynolds in rectangular pipe

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

I work in a lab and i was given the mission of identifing the reynolds in a square pipe, in different flow rates
I have the dimentions of the rectangle - 5cm X 6cm, and I have the flow rate. the fluid is air (so I also have the charecteristics of the fluid)
what is the characteristic length here? and can i assume the speed of the air is the same in all the cross section? (we are talking about q between 30-100 m^3 per hour)

thank you.

Comment: search "Reynolds number" and  "hydraulic diameter"

Answer (score 3):

So, using the formula Hd = (4 * A) / wet perimeter then with 5 and 6 given the Hd is 5.455.

For reference see here :
[Hydraulic Diameter](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/hydraulic-equivalent-diameter-d_458.html)